# Regular expression for specific pattern

Tags: java, javascript, regex, regex-negation

Could anybody help me with regular expression as mentioned.

I have an xml element 'docs' which has an attribute 'range' where range should take only values in the below format.

range = "1,2,3,4,5"

or

range = "1,2,3-6,10-12,15,20-30"

or

range = "all"

A littel help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear to me. What match groups are you expecting? Please post a code sample with your ideal regex match output.

Comment: im validating an xml which has attribute 'range'. It should throw an error when i enter any extra charecters in range except the ones i mentioned above. so i need a regular exp which exactly matches the pattern of values i gave in range(in my question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^\d(?!.*,-)[\d\,\-]*\d$|^all$|^\d+$
```

Should work for your numbers.  Input can only be numbers, commas, or dash or the word `all`.

http://regexr.com?30p7f

Comment: Its not working as required. It is taking the values 1,2,33,abc,@,

Comment: What about `^\d+?[\d,-]+$|all`

Comment: Hey Jack.Thanks for the sol.But it solved 80% only. Still it is having problems with (1,2,3-5,all,). It is taking numbers as well as 'all' also.Either it should be (1,2,3-5,7-9) or (all). And more over no commas at the start and end of the values.

Comment: Ok this regex should do it `^\d+?[\d,-]+[^,]$|^all$` Tell me if it works for you or other cases where it fails.

Comment: it fails for particular scenario where i provide (1,a) or (1,2,@) or (1,2,3-5,#).After comma if it is one char(any) it fails. And if I enter only one number like (1) it is getting failed.

Comment: Ok I changed the `+` to `*` to get `^\d*?[\d,-]*\d$|^all$` This regex covers your scenarios.  Check http://regexr.com/?30p68 Please tell me if it fits your requirements.

Comment: 99% done. Failing for only one scenario comma befor number(,1). Except comma if i give any special character regex works fine.

Comment: Im so worried to say again. it is failing for 1,-2,-3,-4. But any ways thanks a lot..

Comment: Oh right, negative numbers.  You didn't include in your set of examples so I didn't realize.  `^[\-]{0,1}[\d][\d\,\-]*\d$|^all$|^[\-]?\d+$` and http://regexr.com?30p73 hopefully this will be enough for your scenarios...

Comment: No. wat i mean to say is it should not allow -ve numbers. But still it is allowing. It has to be (1,1-2,3-4) but not (1,-2,3-4,-5)

Comment: I see what you mean.  `^\d(?!.*,-)[\d\,\-]*\d$|^all$|^\d+$` http://regexr.com?30p7f I really think this one will work 100%.

Answer (score 2):

`all|[1-9][0-9]*(-[1-9][0-9]*)?(,[1-9][0-9]*(-[1-9][0-9]*)?)*`

I have assumed that zero and leading zeroes are not permitted.

Regular expressions are not a good way to ensure that numbers are in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

As @minopret mentioned, this is probably best not handled completely with regex. I would `split(",")` the strings and then iterate over the resulting array to make sure that they are in ascending order. You can regex each of the individual array elements at that point to make sure they match something like:

```
\d+(-\d+)?
```

Comment: Hi abdullah, I dont have a choice to split the numbers since this is in xsd where im validating my xml against xsd. As soon as the pattern fails i should be thrown as validation error before parsing my xml content.

Comment: Fair enough, although you probably should not have tagged the question with `java` then ;)